# Espresso - how to wait for idle without an assertion/view interaction?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I would like to simply block the instrumentation (test) thread until Espresso is idle.

```
fun test(){
    // do some stuff
    Espresso.waitForIdle()
    // do some more stuff once Espresso reports that the application is idle
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

note: `Espresso.waitForIdle()` is a method I made up

Comment: Espresso synchronizes on main thread only. Most of its `ViewActions` loop main thread until idle. Is there anything in particular you're waiting for, such as a view or network call?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()`. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#waitForIdleSync()

There is also `Espresso.onIdle()`, but the documentation warns `Only call this method for tests that do not interact with any UI elements, but require Espresso's main thread synchronisation!`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#onIdle()

Comment: Will that use idling resources registered in the IdlingRegistry?

Comment: That's a really good question.  `waitForIdleSync` waits until its message queue is empty, but does not interact with IdlingResources.  Here's the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8f6f1f43eeb0d7263b626978ee2c21d4053bf610/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#328

Comment: There's also `Espresso.onIdle()` which appears to do what you want.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#onIdle()

Answer (score 1):

There is also the following:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForIdle {

}
```

which run the code inside lambda after it is idle.

Comment: Thanks! Only one that worked for me when closing a bottom sheet in a Compose UI test